# Expected behaviour for a standard container when comparison object always returns either true or false

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

What is the expected behaviour when the custom comparison object always return same result(could be either true or false but is always same), while putting the elements in a standard library container, say `std::set` or a `std::map`. For example

```
struct A{
   int i_mem;
   double d_mem;
};

bool operator > (const A& first, const A& second)
{
    //This is hard coded just for the sake of example and actual code could still return always return the same value due to bug in the logic.

    return false;
}
```

And then creating the object like

```
set<A, greater<A>> mset{{5,434.5},{1,32.4},{3,29.3}};
```

In this case the set has only first element `(5,434.5)` when tested with g++-10.

Comment: If you violate the strict weak ordering expectation of the container there is no expected behavior.

Comment: [Nasal demons](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't think it actually violates strict-weak ordering. This behaviour just makes all `A`s compare *equivalent* based on how `<` is used for it. This is before C++20 of course.

Comment: @Fureeish The example perhaps, but the question states "could be either true or false but is always same" and always true is a problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja correct, always returning `true` is disasterous, while always returning `false` is completely okay :>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the comparator always returns false then `a < b || b < a` is always `false` so `std::set` will treat all elements as equal and only ever contain one element.

If the comparator always returns true then `a < b && b < a` is always `true` which makes no sense and violates [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) which leads to undefined behaviour.